# Remove for-loop challenge and existence of heuritics to remove for-loops in general

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I don't know if I am taking it too far, but I would like to remove the for loop in the below code:

```
# self.assigments = (N, )
# self.points = (N, D)
# centers = (K, D)
centers = np.zeros((self.K, self.points.shape[1]))
_, counts = np.unique(self.assignments, return_counts=True)
for point, assignment in zip(self.points, self.assignments):
    # The lines below assume D = 2, which is erroneous.
    # It also implies a nested loop over D.
    centers[assignment][0] += point[0] / counts[assignment]
    centers[assignment][1] += point[1] / counts[assignment]
return centers
```

This code basically recalculates the centers of a K-Means cluster algorithm based on assignments. I am struggling to remove the for loop, but my intuition says it can be removed. This got me wondering, are there any rules/heuristics that one can think about while attempting to remove `for`-loops through techniques like vectorization?

My expectation is an answer to whether removal of the `for`-loop from the above code is possible and some rules or heuristics one can apply to optimization through `for`-loop removal in general.

Sample Input & Output:

```
points = np.array([[-1.431,  0.878],
                   [-0.920,  0.488])
assignments = np.array([0, 1])
centers = np.array([[-0.299,  0.224])
output = [[-1.431  0.878 ]
          [-0.920  0.488]]
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there concrete small example (input arrays) + expected output?

Comment: For a start I work from inside out.  Here that means get ride of the separate [0][1] expressions.

Comment: `counts[assignment]` looks suspicious.  This only works if the `_` unique values match `assignments`, and hence counts will all be 1.  But I don't have a [MCVE] or means of testing this.

Comment: Updated the question with sample input and output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### mre

So, I take that assignments is an array of N integers in interval [0,K), assigning each point to a bin.
At what centers is is the mean of each bin.
Right.

Here is a minimal reproducible example of the problem as I understand it

```py
N=5
K=3
np.random.seed(0)
assignments = np.random.randint(0,K,(N,))
points = np.random.rand(N,2)
centers = np.zeros((K,2))
_, counts = np.unique(assignments, return_counts=True)
for point, assignment in zip(points, assignments):
    centers[assignment][0] += point[0] / counts[assignment]
    centers[assignment][1] += point[1] / counts[assignment]
```

Result being

```
array([[0.43102341, 0.55485167],
       [0.45758964, 0.33427908],
       [0.        , 0.        ]])
```

Which seems consistent, since points and assignments are

```
#points
array([[0.38438171, 0.29753461],
       [0.05671298, 0.27265629],
       [0.47766512, 0.81216873],
       [0.47997717, 0.3927848 ],
       [0.83607876, 0.33739616]])
#assignments
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```

So, first center is sum of points 0 and 2, divided by 2, and second sum of 1,3 and 4, divided by 3.

### error if some assignment never occur

Before we get to vectorization, first note that we were lucky that it even worked like this. Just change the seed to 13, and result is different

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Reason is easily understandable looking as `assignments` and `counts`

```
# assignments
array([2, 0, 2, 0, 2])
# counts
array([2, 3])
```

So, your code relies on all possible values existing at least once.

Since we don't know where `assignments` comes from, maybe that is true. But if that is false, then your code risk failing when some assignments do not happen.

So, my first suggestion would be to change your way to create counts

```py
counts=np.zeros((K,), dtype=int)
v,c=np.unique(assignments, return_counts=True)
counts[v]=c
```

Which, in addition to correcting an error in your code, gives you a first hint of how vectorization can be done on array indexation: `v` here is an array of int.

So adding the improvement suggested by hpaulj (or a variant of it), our code is now

```
N=5
K=3
np.random.seed(0)
assignments = np.random.randint(0,K,(N,))
points = np.random.rand(N,2)
centers = np.zeros((K,2))
counts=np.zeros((K,), dtype=int)
v,c=np.unique(assignments, return_counts=True)
counts[v]=c
for point, assignment in zip(points, assignments):
    centers[assignment] += point / counts[assignment]
```

Giving of course the exact same result

It would be tempting now to continue that vectorization by doing

```py
centers[assignments] += points / counts[assignments, None]
```

But this doesn't work. It gives

```
array([[0.23883256, 0.40608436],
       [0.27869292, 0.11246539],
       [0.        , 0.        ]])
```

Which, as we can easily check, is, for each bin, counting only the last point
(0.2388 is 0.47766512/2, and 0.27869282 is 0.83607876/3).

Because that is like computing `centers[assignments] + points / counts[assignments, None]` and assigning those values to `centers[assignment]`. So exactly as `centers[[0,1,0]]=[1,2,3]` means that `centers[0]` is now 3 and `centers[1]` is 2 (and value 1, that was briefly assigned to `centers[0]` has been overwritten), all but that values of each bin are overwritten.

### Iterating over K bins instead of N points

One method, still using a for loop, but a smaller one (well, I take that K is supposed to be smaller than N) would be to loop over the bins

```
for k in range(K):
    mask = assignments==k
    centers[k] = points[mask].sum(axis=0) / counts[k]
```

But if one bin is empty, that leads to division by 0. Which is easily solved by iterating only existing value (we have already computed this array, called `v` earlier)

```
for k in v:
    mask = assignments==k
    centers[k] = points[mask].sum(axis=0) / counts[k]
```

Which gives still the same result as earlier, with less iterations (v cannot be bigger than N. And I expect that it is even way smaller).

### bincount or iterating over 2 dimensions

Since hpaulj mentionned `bincount`, we can indeed use it. But not in one line.

`bincount` is just what you did with `unique`. I didn't mentioned it before, because I needed the values (my `v` vector). But you didn't. You ignored values output of `unique`, to keep only `counts`.
In that case, you could have used `bincount` : `counts = np.bincount(assignments)`.
That is what `bincount` does.

But it is not just a less capable version of `unique` (I mean a version of `unique` that can't provide list of values). `bincount` also accept an optional variable `weights`, and it that case, what it returns it a weighted count.

For example,

```
np.bincount([0,1,2,0,1], [10,5,2,1,1])
```

returns an array of 3 values (since there are 3 `bins`, 3 possible values):
`[10+1, 5+1, 2]=[11,6,2]`

Note another difference between `bincounts` and `unique`: it counts all possible values between 0 and the max value. Including those that never occur.

`np.unique([3,3,5], return_counts=True)[1]`
returns `[2,1]`

while `np.bincount([3,3,5])`
returns `array([0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1])`

So, that could have also solved our previous problem (but, again, I needed `v` anyway).

So, now, if we compute
`np.bincount(assignments, weights=points[:,0])`
we get
`array([0.86204682, 1.37276891])`

Which is, for each of the two possible values. Since, `2` never occur with the current seed, 0, there are only 2 values (if it had been 0 or 1 that never occured, like we seed 13, we would have got 3 values, one being 0). It would be better to have `K`. We can force `K` values using optional argument `minlength`

```py
np.bincount(assignments, weights=points[:,0], minlength=K)
```

So those are for each value k in range(0,K), the sum of `points[:,0][k]`, that is `points[k,0]`.

To get what we want we need to divide by the number of points in each bin

```py
np.bincount(assignments, weights=points[:,0], minlength=K) / np.bincount(assignments, minlength=K)
```

We get
`array([0.43102341, 0.45758964,        nan])`

Those are the `x` values of the expected `centers`.

Likewise

```py
np.bincount(assignments, weights=points[:,1], minlength=K) / np.bincount(assignments, minlength=K)
```

Returns
`array([0.55485167, 0.33427908,        nan])`

which are the `y` values of the `centers` we expect

Well, almost there. There is this `nan`.
It could be tempting to say "but this is because you added this `minlength=K`". Indeed, without it, we would have just computed this for the two non-0 cases. But that would have solved only the case when it is value K-1 that never occur. For seed 13, for example, we would still have a problem.

One solution is simply to ensure that the divisor is never 0 (after all, in those 0 cases, we don't really care, since numerator is 0 also).

Hence my final ansewr

```py
N=5
K=3
np.random.seed(0)
assignments = np.random.randint(0,K,(N,))
points = np.random.rand(N,2)
centers = np.zeros((K,2))
bc=np.maximum(1, np.bincount(assignments, minlength=K))
centers[:,0] = np.bincount(assignments, minlength=K, weights=points[:,0])/bc
centers[:,1] = np.bincount(assignments, minlength=K, weights=points[:,1])/bc
```

Giving the same result as before.

Note that there is still a for loop (here unrolled: I repeated the line twice).
It doesn't iterate over N points, nor over K possible values, but over the (here) 2 dimensions.
But the fact that, in your own code, you replaced `2` by `points.shape[1]` means that the dimension might not be 2. So you might need to do an actual `for` loop

```py
for dim in range(points.shape[1]):
    centers[:,dim] = np.bincount(assignments, minlength=K, weights=points[:,dim])/bc
```

But, well, I suppose we can expect that the dimension of your points are well under both N and K.

### Timings

For N=1000000 points, K=100 bins, and Dim=3 dimensions (that is the 1000000 points are triplets (x,y,z) of coordinates in a 3d-space),
timings are as follows (on my rather slow PC):

| Method | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| Initial (iterations over N and Dim) | 4151 ms |
| Iterations over K | 693 ms |
| Last solution (iterations over just Dim) | 29 ms |

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the detailed answers, with error handling details.
This is indeed getting close to removing the for-loop, and all your assumptions are on point.
The general takeaway is that the first thing is, to find ways of reducing the number of iterations in the loop before the ambitious aim of removing it. . .

Comment: @lambda07 Plus, after all, the last remaining one (the one over the dimensions of your space) is the one you already got (also unrolled: your solution have in reality 2 nested loops, one over the N points, and another, unrolled, over the 2 dimensins, 0 and 1, of your points), So, this removed one of the 2 loops :)

Comment: Ahh, you are right, never thought about it in this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What does `counts[self.assignments]` produce?  A (N,) array?

```
self.points   # (N,2)
temp = self.points/counts[self.assignments][:,None]
```

should be (N,2).  So my guess is

```
for assignment in self.assignments:
    centers[assignment] += temp[assignment]
```

That doesn't get rid of the big `N` loop, but may make visualizing that `+=` assignment easier.

At the back of my mind I'm thinking `bincount` might be useful here.  But I haven't used that function much.

I guess that illustrates my dual approach - clean up the inner 'vectorization' as much as possible, followed by visualization of the main iteration.

Comment: Yup, you are right, and this does clean the nested loop for handling D. Thanks!